# Getting Dynamic Linking working on classic ASP pages

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am currently doing a fresh installation of Tridion 2011. We were previously using 5.3 and are keeping the database. I have so far installed the database, content manager, two content delivery servers and am now working on setting up the presentation servers. All of our web pages are built using classic asp. I was advised that I should manually install the API (linking, broker and WAI) if I wanted my asp pages to use dynamic linking (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12428237/1113475)

I have read through the documentation and it explains how to install the API as a .NET web service. I don't think this is what I want as my web pages are all classic asp. I assume I need to do something with the exe files in the `Content Delivery\roles\api\windows` directory but they do nothing when I run them.

When running the following code on my asp page

```
Server.CreateObject("cd_link.ComponentLink")
```

I get the error

> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
>
> Server.CreateObject Failed
>
> /about/index.asp, line 196
>
> 800401f3

... but this is obviously going to happen as I've not got the linker installed

#### Additional Information

Server is 64 bit Windows Server 2008. Running IIS 7.5 but my application pool for Tridion 2011 is running in 32bit mode.

Creating other third party objects works fine. Like the Chilkat Crypt library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Live Documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_37579189E2264514837918B57EC3DCD1):

1. From each machine that runs a Content Delivery Server Role, open a Windows command prompt, access the SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 installation media, navigate to the folder Content Delivery\roles\api\windows.
2. Install the deprecated Windows services by running the following commands:

cd_broker.exe -install

cd_wai.exe -install

cd_link.exe -install

Comment: Even if the documentation doesn't mention it, on my experience it is best to copy first the exe files to /Tridion_Root/bin folder and then run the commands from there

Comment: Good point @Puntero, chances are that it will try to install the services from the _current_ location, which could be on the network or c:\temp...

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I copied the exe's in to Tridion/bin folder and installed the services as suggested. However, the services don't actually start. I get a message `The Tridion Dynamic Linking service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.`. In the event log I get a message `The description for Event ID 100 from source TCDLink cannot be found. Either the com...` and additional information `Could not load Java runtime libraries at`. Java 6 v35 is definitely installed.

Comment: You need to install the Java 32 bits for the old linking services to work. I guess you probably have the 64 bits installed. In your case you need to install both of them (yes they are compatible).

Comment: yup, all COM/ASP services are 32 bit. Yes, it is time to consider finally moving away from Classic ASP...